# Meteor - how to change page title with route/page changes, NOT using JS

Tags: meteor

I'm building a site with Meteor, and it *has* to be SEO-friendly. This means that page titles must all reflect the content. When the user navigates to different pages, I need the page title to change, but it has to be served up from the back-end, not changed via Javascript, as spiders won't pick up on that.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can render templates into HTML pages on the server side using Arunoda's SSR package - https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr

Comment: Man I feel dumb. I can't figure out how to piece that in so it drops different content into `<head>` based on what page the user is on.

Comment: I haven't used SSR yet, but presumably use iron:router server routes and repeat the `<head>` in the templates?

Comment: Use server side rendering (not sure about meteorhacks:ssr), with manuelschoebel:ms-seo.  This will result in the page seo stuff getting set for spiders.  Be sure to declare your routes on both, rather than just on client.

Comment: I think spiderable + manuelschoebel:ms-seo may be what you're after.

Comment: Ugh. I'm too much of a Meteor n00b. Looking at ms-seo, I have no idea where any of that code is supposed to go.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack just forget about server side rendering except for performance reasons. Meteor does everything through javascript with an initial empty page. But to accomplish SEO, it has the spiderable package which serves a server generated page to search engine crawlers. As an alternative to spiderable, you can use prerender.io and of course as already said, ms-seo for managing the contents of your head